# ItemsControl different template based on Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

Could some identify why the following is not working please, I am trying to implement a Chat Message window where each Message will render a different style dependent on the `MessageDirection`. For this I am using a `ItemsControl` which is bound to the `Messages` property

In the ChatWindow class I have the following

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MessagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Messages",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Message>),
        typeof(ChatWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<Message>)this.GetValue(MessagesProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetValue(MessagesProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I have the following defined in a ResourceDictionary

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="srcMessages" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chat:ChatWindow}}}" x:Name="Messages">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <chat:MessageContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                        <chat:MessageContentPresenter.InboundTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="94" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Username One" FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" - " FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="11:45 AM" FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="60" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                            <Image.Clip>
                                                <EllipseGeometry Center="30,30" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" />
                                            </Image.Clip>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Polygon Grid.Column="3" Points="0,0 -4,3 0,6 0,0" StrokeThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#d8d7dc" Stroke="#d8d7dc"></Polygon>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="#d8d7dc" BorderThickness="1" Background="#d8d7dc" Padding="5">
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a message in a chat window..." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" Foreground="#000000"></TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </chat:MessageContentPresenter.InboundTemplate>
                        <chat:MessageContentPresenter.OutboundTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="94" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Username One" FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" - " FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="11:45 AM" FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Grid.Column="4" Height="60" Width="60" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                            <Image.Clip>
                                                <EllipseGeometry Center="30,30" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" />
                                            </Image.Clip>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Polygon Grid.Column="2" Points="0,0 4,3 0,6 0,0" StrokeThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#4fcd00" Stroke="#4fcd00"></Polygon>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#4fcd00" BorderThickness="1" Background="#4fcd00" Padding="5">
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a message in a chat window..." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" Foreground="#000000"></TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </chat:MessageContentPresenter.OutboundTemplate>
                    </chat:MessageContentPresenter>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And the MessageContentPresenter is as below

```
public class MessageContentPresenter : ContentControl
{
    #region Public Properties

    public DataTemplate InboundTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate OutboundTemplate { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        var message = newContent as Message;
        if (message.Direction == MessageDirection.Inbound)
        {
            this.ContentTemplate = this.InboundTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ContentTemplate = this.OutboundTemplate;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I run this code all works fine and the `OnContentChanged` method is executed once for each item in the `Messages` collection. The issue is that both the `InboundTemplate` and the `OutboundTemplate` are `null`.

I really cannot see what the problem is so and why the two templates are both `null`, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `Content` property is set before inbound and outbound templates. I think it would be better to use custom [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do you have an example implementation based on the above

Comment: I don't have access to PC at the moment but MSDN site from the link above should have one

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can use DataTemplateSelector.

But another option is to use the DataTemplate + ContentControl and Style:

First, drop your `MessageContentPresenter` class as we do not need it. Consequently, you need to remove your `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` from your XAML.

Secondly, add DataTemplate + ContentControl and Style to your Window.Resources.

Try this to give you some lead:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Message}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Direction}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Direction}" Value="{x:Static local:MessageDirection.Inbound}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Background="Green">Inbound</Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Direction}" Value="{x:Static local:MessageDirection.Outbound}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Background="Red">Outbound</Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what originally looked at but the design I have is similar to the iOS text conversation where the Inbound and Outbound templates are Left aligned and Right aligned respectively, not just a different colour but the layout is also different which is what led me to the approach I took

Comment: It is a DataTemplate, so you can do that. I just put a button there for brevity but you can add your desired Content.

Comment: I have implemented the above and i am now able to get the correct template to load, however, within the template i am trying to bind to properites of `Message` but they are all empty, what am i doing wrong? example `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="10" Foreground="#adadad"></TextBlock>` but when i run the application this is always blank

Comment: Think i found the issue, i changed this `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Direction}">` to `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">` and all works fine now